# FactoryBot attributes seems to be invisible to method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec, capybara, factory-bot

On my test I have factories like this:

```
Spec.feature 'Estabelecimentos', type: :feature, js: true, inspector: true, feature: true do
  given!(:estado) { create(:estado) }
  given!(:cidade) { create(:municipio) }
  given!(:endereco) { create(:endereco) }
  given!(:grupo) { create(:grupo) }
  given!(:user_admin) { create(:usuario, role: 'ADMIN') }


  before do
    FactoryBot.create(:mcc)
    FactoryBot.create(:modelo_pagamento)
    FactoryBot.create(:supervisor)
    FactoryBot.create(:representante)
    FactoryBot.create(:categoria_estabelecimento)
    FactoryBot.create(:empresa_ancora)
  end
```

But on mcc.rb, I have:

```
class Mcc < ApplicationRecord
  audited

  before_save :params_to_uppercase

  def params_to_uppercase
    descricao.upcase!
  end

  def id_desc
    codigo.to_s << " - " << descricao.upcase!
  end
end
```

I'm creating a mcc using

```
FactoryBot.create(:mcc)
```

But this method on mcc.rb:

```
 def id_desc
    codigo.to_s << " - " << descricao.upcase!
  end
```

is breaking my test with this error:

```
 Failure/Error: codigo.to_s << " - " << descricao.upcase!
     
     ActionView::Template::Error:
       no implicit conversion of nil into String
     # ./app/models/mcc.rb:13:in `id_desc'
     # ./app/views/estabelecimentos/_dados.html.erb:112:in `block in _app_views_estabelecimentos__dados_html_erb___4252541458763635733_70174788728900'
     # ./app/views/estabelecimentos/_dados.html.erb:29:in `_app_views_estabelecimentos__dados_html_erb___4252541458763635733_70174788728900'
     # ./app/views/estabelecimentos/new.html.erb:15:in `_app_views_estabelecimentos_new_html_erb___2421282149664823985_70174788563040'
     # ------------------
     # --- Caused by: ---
     # TypeError:
     #   no implicit conversion of nil into String
     #   ./app/models/mcc.rb:13:in `id_desc'
```

codigo and descricao are attributes of mcc, so they should be created when I create mcc. my mcc factory on factories.rb:

```
 factory :mcc do
    id { Mcc.all.order(:id).last.nil? ? 1 : Mcc.all.order(:id).last.id + 1 }
    codigo { 1 }
    descricao { 'MCC TESTE' }
    cnae { 1 }
    created_at { DateTime.now }
    updated_at { DateTime.now }
  end
```

Is there a way to do this? how can I fix it?

Comment: Your issue is that `descricao` is already all upper case. In this event `descricao.upcase!` returns `nil` (e.g. no substitution was made)

Answer (score 0):

Your variables descricao or codigo is nil, the error is in type casting nil to string.
Use binding.pry or byebug to debugger and to search where these variables should be initialized and aren't.

Comment: codigo and descricao are attributes of mcc, so they shouldn't be nil.

Answer (score 0):

Luiz Romário resolved. Just replace:

```
codigo.to_s << " - " << descricao.upcase!
```

with

```
"#{codigo.to_s} - #{descricao.upcase}"
```

Comment: It's worth pointing out that in Ruby string interpolated objects are automatically called with to_s, so this can simply be `"#{codigo} - #{descricao.upcase}"`